# How to add a ScrollView to my TableviewController class?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiscrollview, uitableview

I have a tableviewController class where i am displaying my content in the tableview. Here, i want to add a scrollview below the tableview but i am not able to change the tableview coordinates. My TableviewController is in turn added to a navigation controller. As of now i am able to add the scrollview using `self.view addsubview:myScrollView` but it is getting added to the tableview. When i scroll the tableview the scrollview is also getting scrolled vertically. But i want the scrollview to be fixed below the tableview and i just want my scrollview to scroll just horizontally. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems what is happening is that you are adding a UIScrollView on top of the view stack and so causing it to rest on top of the UITableViewController instead of beside it. This is not good.

You should consider using UIViewController instead of UITableViewController. You could then subview a UITableView with a UINavigationController and a separate UIScrollView to fit the screen how you want it.

This is a pretty major undertaking, so it will be hard to demonstrate a good answer in code.

Comment: Thanks...will try to implement the same and let u know if this approach works.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is make your view controller a subclass of UIViewController, then add UITableViewDatasource and UITableViewDelegate protocol in your header file. If you are instantiating in NIB, toss your Tableview instance and replace it with UIView. You then hook to your FilesOwner as your view. then bring in table view object from the library and hook its delegate and datasource to file owner and you should be good! Hope this work well for you. Work well for me all the time!